# ¿Por qué me sale este error en NodeJS? UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy trabajando con express y mongodb.

Y me encuentro realizando un CRUD para usuarios, tengo un controlador que hace las operaciones.

Uno de los métodos se encarga de actualizar el username y email del usuario, por lo cual quiero elaborar un método donde se actualice únicamente el password.

Tengo algo de esta manera:

```
exports.updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id   = req.params.id;
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['username', 'email']);

    if(req.body.password){
        next();
    }

    try {
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, body, {new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query'});
        res.json({msg: 'success'});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            msg: 'fail',
            error
        });
        next();
    }
}


exports.updateUserPassword = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const body = req.body.password;

    if(req.body.password === null || req.body.password === undefined || req.body.password === ''){
        next();
    }

    try {

        await User.findOneAndUpdate(id, body, {new: true, context: 'query'});
        res.json({msg: 'success'});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            msg: 'fail',
            error
        });
        next();
    }

}
```

Funcionan parcialmente, el problema es que cuando realizo el método para actualizar la consola me arroja lo siguiente:

> (node:19920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
>   [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\ID139\Documents\Projects\social_net\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
>   at ServerResponse.send
>   (C:\Users\ID139\Documents\Projects\social_net\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>   at ServerResponse.json
>   (C:\Users\ID139\Documents\Projects\social_net\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
>   at exports.updateUser
>   (C:\Users\ID139\Documents\Projects\social_net\controllers\user.controller.js:57:25)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) (node:19920)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:19920) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

A pesar de esto, se cumple la operación de actualizar únicamente la contraseña. ¿Alguna recomendación para evitar este "error" u optimizar el código?

De ser necesario, estas son las rutas:

```
router.put('/users/:id', UserController.updateUser);
router.put('/users/:id', UserController.updateUserPassword);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que estás tratando de responder dos veces a una única petición:

Por un lado tienes:

```
router.put('/users/:id', UserController.updateUser);
router.put('/users/:id', UserController.updateUserPassword);
```

y por otro tienes:

```
exports.updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id   = req.params.id;
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['username', 'email']);
    const status = {};

    if(req.body.password){
        next(); // <----AQUI
    }

    try {
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, body, {new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query'});
        status.msg = 'success';
        status.code = 200;
    } catch (error) {
        status.msg = 'fail';
        status.code = 400;
        next();
    }
    res.json(status);
}
```

Te he marcado la línea importante: tu código decide que lo que se está modificando es el password y delega en el siguiente *middleware*... pero cuando el siguiente (la función `updateUserPassword`) termina, no haces un return, el código de `updateUser` ¡sigue ejecutándose!.

Prueba a añadir una línea:

```
...
if(req.body.password){
    next(); // <----AQUI
    return; //hemos terminado, no sigamos ejecutando
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, resolvio el problema, de igual manera tuve que cambiar un poco la logica de mi codigo para que funcionara aun mucho mejor, gracias nuevamente!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente

```
exports.updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id   = req.params.id;
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['username', 'email']);
    const status = {};

    if(req.body.password){
        next();
    }

    try {
        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, body, {new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query'});
        status.msg = 'success';
        status.code = 200;
    } catch (error) {
        status.msg = 'fail';
        status.code = 400;
        next();
    }
    res.json(status);
}


exports.updateUserPassword = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const body = req.body.password;
    const status = {};

    if(req.body.password === null || req.body.password === undefined || req.body.password === ''){
        next();
    }

    try {

        await User.findOneAndUpdate(id, body, {new: true, context: 'query'});
        status.msg = 'success';
        status.code = 200;
    } catch (error) {
        status.msg = 'fail';
        status.code = 400;
        next();
    }
    res.json(status);
}
```

[Explicación (ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)